# Which framework should I use to write modules?

Tags: perl, perl-module

What's the best framework for writing modules -- [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ExtUtils::MakeMaker) (h2xs) or [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Build)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**NOTE** This advice is out of date.  [Module::Build has been removed from the Perl core](http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2140/paying-respect-to-modulebuild/) but lives on as a CPAN module.  The pros and cons still stand, and my opinions about MakeMaker still stand.

---

As the former maintainer of ExtUtils::MakeMaker, I like to recommend Module::Build because MakeMaker is a horror show.  Module::Build is so much better put together.  But those aren't your concerns and I'll present my "least hassle for you" answer.

### Executive Summary:

Because Module::Build support is not 100% in place through all of Perl, start with MakeMaker.  If you want to do any customization at all, switch to Module::Build.  Since their basic layout, options and interface are almost identical this will be painless.  As seductive as it looks, avoid Module::Install.

Fortunately, Module::Build can emulate MakeMaker which helps some, but doesn't help if you're going to do any customization.  See [Module::Build::Compat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build::Compat).

For CPAN releases using Module::Build is fine.  There's enough Module::Build stuff on CPAN now that everyone's dealt with getting it bootstrapped already.

Finally, the new [`configure_requires`](http://module-build.sourceforge.net/META-spec.html#configure_requires) option lets CPAN shells know to install Module::Build before they can start building the module.  Unfortunately only the latest CPAN shells know about configure_requires.

Oh, whatever you do don't use h2xs (unless you're writing XS code... and even then think about it).

### MakeMaker Pros:

- Comes with Perl and used by the Perl core (therefore it is actively
  maintained and will remain so forever)
- Everything knows what to do with a Makefile.PL.
- Most module authoring documentation will cover MakeMaker.
- Uses make (those who know make can debug and patch the build
  process)

### MakeMaker Cons:

- Requires make (think Windows)
- Difficult to customize
- Even harder to customize and make cross platform
- Difficult to debug when something goes wrong (unless you understand make)

### Module::Build Pros:

- Easier to customize/subclass
- Pure Perl
- Easier to debug (it's Perl)
- Can emulate MakeMaker in several ways
- The CPAN shell will install Module::Build for you

### Module::Build Cons:

- The Module::Build maintainers (and indeed all of the Perl Toolchain Gang) hate it
- Older versions of CPAN clients (including CPANPLUS) don't know anything about Module::Build.

### Module::Install Pros:

- Slick interface
- Bundles itself, you have a known version
- Everything knows how to deal with a Makefile.PL

### Module::Install Cons:

- Requires make
- Always uses bundled version, vulnerable to external breakage
- Difficult to customize outside its interface
- Mucks with the guts of MakeMaker so a new MakeMaker release will eventually break it.
- Does not know how to generate a META file using the v2 meta-spec
  (increasingly a problem with newer tools)

Comment: If I recall correctly, CPANPLUS cannot uninstall modules that it installed using Module::Build, but it can uninstall them if they were installed using MakeMaker. So that's a con for M::B.

Comment: @Ryan That doesn't appear to be true, just tried it on Acme::Pony (MakeMaker) and Gravatar::URL (Module::Build).  CPANPLUS' uninstall is packlist based, and there may have been a time when MB didn't produce packlists.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on Ubuntu 9.10. Since perl is such a core component of the OS, I know that Debian/Ubuntu tends to update it infrequently. Maybe I'm just living in the past.

Comment: Module::Build has been pissing me off lately. Try to install DBM::Deep — it kvetches about missing pre-reqs, doesnt’t install them, but manages to succeed anyway. It is quite deceptive.

Comment: @tchrist You should know that the responsibility for installing prereqs falls to your CPAN shell, not Module::Build nor MakeMaker.  You should also know that this is not the bug queue for any of those things.  Since you're having trouble finding it, here's DBM::Deep's: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=DBM-Deep

Comment: This advice is quite old, and now out of date. The Perl Toolchain Gang does not recommend using Module::Build unless needed.  http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2140/paying-respect-to-modulebuild/

Comment: @Ether I'd prefer updates to the pros and cons in the answer than a fiat stamp saying which one to use (the blessing of Toolchain would be a pro).  I've done some small updates, but my knowledge of where the various build systems are at is out of date.  Dist::Zilla should also be included.

Comment: I've made another editing pass to add some pros/cons.  Also please note that Module::Build::Compat is even more of a $%-show than vanilla MB, so if you *can* produce a MB-Compat-generated Makefile.PL and not lose any functionality, *please please* just use ExtUtils::MakeMaker. The toolchain gang will thank you.

Comment: Also, note that if you use Dist::Zilla, you can sidestep all these issues listed above -- the front end is *much* nicer as you just present all of your prereqs in a list, and the underlying Makefile.PL is generated for you by `[MakeMaker]` so its messy syntax is not something you have to worry about.

Answer (score 35):

There are two questions here.

First, never use h2xs. It's old outdated nastiness, though I suppose if you're actually trying to turn a header file into XS code, it might be useful (never done that myself).

**2011 update: I strongly recommend taking a look at [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org), especially if you think you'll be maintaining more than one module.**

For creating a new module, use Module::Starter. It works great, and has some nice plugins for customizing the output.

Second, you're asking what build system you should use. The three contenders are ExtUtils::MakeMaker (EUMM), Module::Build (MB), and Module::Install (MI).

EUMM is a horrid nasty piece of work, but it works, and if you're not customizing your build process at all, works just fine.

MB is the new kid, and it has its detractors. It's big plus is that if you want to heavily customize your install and build process, it's quite possible to do this sanely (and in a cross-platform manner) using MB. It's really not possible using EUMM.

Finally, MI is basically a declarative wrapper on top of EUMM. It also packages itself along with your distro, in an attempt to work around problems with users trying to install modules with old toolchain modules. The downside of the "package self" trick is that if there's a bug in MI itself, you have to re-release all your modules just to fix it.

As far as customization goes, there are some plugins for MI, but if you want to go beyond them you'll be back at the problem of dealing with Makefiles and build tools across a dozen+ platforms, so it really isn't going to help you too much in that realm.

Answer (score 20):

I just uploaded [Distribution::Cooker](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Distribution-Cooker) to CPAN. It's what I use to make new distributions. The nice thing about it is that your distributions can be whatever you like: you're just cooking some templates. I don't care if anyone uses it. For me it's simple, low tech, and doesn't cause extra problems.

You might start with something like [Module::Starter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Starter) to make your starter templates then add your own boilerplate and favorite way of doing things. You choose not only whatever you want in each file, but which files show up in the distro. As you figure out how you like to do things, you simply update your own templates.

As for Makemaker and Module::Build, <s>the future is Module::Build</s>. It's only us old guys using Makemaker anymore. :) There are ways to use both (or pretend to use both) at the same time. <s>Look at the Module::Build, Module::Build::Compat, and Module::Install docs</s>. Module::Build was kicked out of Perl's Standard Library and it's future is uncertain. It's back to Makemaker as a build system.

Although this is a bit of a cop-out answer, try using each just to get a little experience with each.

Comment: The future may have been Module::Build but that time has now come and gone :)  http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/2140/paying-respect-to-modulebuild/

Answer (score 14):

You also might want to look at [Dist-Zilla](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla/) which is a new author-only tool to create distributions.  Because it just helps build the distribution, it doesn't ship with your code or do any installation, it can do a lot of powerful stuff.

Comment: +1: Dist::Zilla is the new sex.

Comment: Combining both of your posts @Schwern , you should use Dist::Zilla with [ModuleBuild] plugin =). http://p3rl.org/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ModuleBuild

Answer (score 7):

The only trouble with compatibility regarding Module::Build is when a user tries to install modules without updating their CPAN client (CPAN.pm or CPANPLUS.pm)  If they are installing your module from the CPAN, they can just as easily upgrade their client from the same mirror.

If you don't want to do *anything* complicated in your build process, sure: use EUMM.  But if you have a build problem on a different target platform, you might end up in the Makefile, which is different on every variation of make.

Module::Build gives you lots of features (anything you can think of if you extend it) and is all perl so you never end up debugging a makefile.  Module::Install gives you features, but you have to bundle it and everything ends up running through 'make' in the end.

Comment: Not everyone installs via the cpan shell so dependency resolution isn't necessarily automatic. I've had a hard time trying to get it to work with ActivePerl (though it seems to be okay now in 5.10). That said, I think your second paragraph is the key answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are pros and cons to both.  These days I use and recommend Module::Build and Module::Starter.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend Module::Build and Module::Starter (with the [TT2 plugin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Starter::Plugin::TT2)).

Answer (score 2):

Module::Build is better by any means, but it is less widely supported than ExtUtils::MakeMaker (more specifically, older versions of Perl don't support it out of the box). It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I recommend Module::Install, as do a lot of folks I know - the likes of the Catalyst and Moose folks also use it.

Comment: Well, Moose moved away from it for Class::MOP, so I could add some make the XS optional bits that would've been painful to do in MI. And that is the crux of (one reason) why I don't like MI. It's a very narrow API, and customizing it is even more painful than dealing with EUMM.

Comment: Module::Install looks very nice, but you distribute it with your module so you're stuck with whatever version you distribute. I don't like having another set of things to update in a dist either. Aside from that, Module::Install is nice as long as you don't use auto_install. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little clarification of the direction I hoped the responses would take:

- pros/cons of various of frameworks
- compatibility/install base of frameworks
- suitability for internal (local) vs. external (CPAN) releases
- *not* bare "use X" answers

[Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73889/which-framework-should-i-use-to-write-modules#74216) has some good pro/con info. [Leon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73889/which-framework-should-i-use-to-write-modules#74133) alludes to compatibility but isn't explicit. As [brian d foy mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73889/which-framework-should-i-use-to-write-modules#74628), only the old hats use EUMM, but I'm not convinced that MB is a good framework for things destined for CPAN due to it not being part of the core until 5.9.

Comment: The core module problem is why I haven't used Module::Build yet, but now that 5.10 has it, I should probably use Module::Build now. Even though 5.10 isn't widely distributed yet (still being 5.10.0), if I start a module I don't want to have to redo it's build system later. :)

Answer (score 0):

EU::MM still seems to be the most widely supported and popular one, but Module::Build is catching up. Also, check out [Module::Starter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Starter/) for a module that will help you get started.