# Makefile.PL: Installing multiple scripts and binaries

Tags: perl, makefile

Given a `Makefile.PL`, how can I install two binaries and two scripts in four different locations?

To be more precise, the directory structure is as follows:

- lib/my_package/main.pl
- bin/daemon/daemon.pl (*)
- bin/plugin/plugin.pl (*)
- scripts/conf/conf.sh (*)
- scripts/init/initd.sh (*)
- Makefile.PL

The files marked with (*) should be installed in the following paths:

- /usr/sbin/daemon.pl
- /var/qmail/smtpplugins/plugin.pl
- /usr/local/conf.sh
- /etc/init.d/initd.sh

and the contents of my `Makefile.PL`

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    NAME         => "my_package",
    VERSION_FROM => "lib/my_package/main.pl"
);
```

What do I tell perl through the `Makefile.PL` to make it install those four files in their corresponding directories?

Comment: A "makefile.pl" tag would have been good

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that the names of the directories are preserved, but the names of the files have been changed to protect the innocent :)

Comment: Did you check `perldoc ExtUtils::MakeMaker`?

Comment: Related: [Which framework should I use to write modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73889/which-framework-should-i-use-to-write-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch to `Module::Build`, you can simply use
[`install_path`](http://p3rl.org/Module::Build::API#install_path).

Comment: Not what I hope for, but why not?

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas from the `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` documentation:

Use the `PL_FILES` parameter. To paraphrase the documentation:
 `PL_FILES => {'bin/install.PL' => 'an-arg'}` would run `bin/foobar.PL` as `perl bin/installPL an-arg`

Or have MakeMaker add a new target to the generated `makefile` using the `postamble` feature.

Or, yes, `Module::Install` or `Dist::Zilla` (there's probably yet another Perl module to do it since I last looked, lively little language that it is).